# Format timestamp according to RFC 3339 with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Like this:

```
const RFC_3339 = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss';
moment.utc().format(RFC_3339);
```

I need the timestamp to have a 'Z' at the end. Is there a better way than just `+'Z'`?

It should match the python code on the backend:

```
RFC_3339_FMT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

Comment: Why can't you just use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)? As the docs says: _As of version **1.5.0**, calling `moment#format` without a format will default to `moment.defaultFormat`. Out of the box, `moment.defaultFormat` is the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ.`. As of version **2.13.0**, when in UTC mode, the default format will return `Z` as the offset, instead of `+00:00`_

Comment: Does it work for you? I am still gettting `+00:00`.
`moment.version` "2.7.0" `moment.utc().format()` "2016-11-01T22:35:42+00:00". The docs say I am in UTC mode whenever calling `.utc()`. So I would assume it works.

Comment: Note that the docs says that you will have the `Z` instead of the `+00:00` starting from version **2.13.0**, you are using **2.7.0** that is previous.

Comment: My bad, my bad. I just fiddled around with the latest version and it works. Thanks a lot! If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can simply use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

As the docs says:

> As of version **1.5.0**, calling `moment#format` without a format will default to `moment.defaultFormat`. Out of the box, `moment.defaultFormat` is the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`.
>
> As of version **2.13.0**, when in UTC mode, the default format will return `Z` as the offset, instead of `+00:00`

Comment: > As of version 2.13.0, when in UTC mode, the default format will return Z as the offset, instead of +00:00

Interestingly enough, I got `+00:00` when I used `format()` on a UTC server (Heroku), and Google Calendar API, which is RFC 3339 - compliant, returned an error and worked only with `Z` offset

Using momentjs version 2.20

Comment: @PetrGazarov please note that [_UTC mode_](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) depends on the way you create moment object, not on the environment offset. `moment().format()` will print `+00:00` on a UTC server, while `moment.utc().format()` will have `Z`. For more info see [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) and [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @VincenzoC

Answer (score 7):

I think that the `toISOString()` function does what you need, right?
See the [documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).

Comment: Unfortunately I need the TS without milliseconds.